# Azure Web Role: How to get the latest publish/deploy date programmatically in a ASP.NET MVC Project

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure

I'm hoping there is an object or method in the Azure Tools for .NET API, that can provide deployment information, that can be accessed in an ASP.NET MVC project that is deployed in an Azure Web Role. Is anyone aware of anything like that in the Azure tools API?

Comment: Hi, just to verify, so your ASP.NET MVC application is hosted in a Azure Cloud Service (Web Role), is this correct?

Comment: What deployment information are you trying to get?

Comment: @juvchan, yes, that is correct.

Comment: @Chase, currently, I'm mostly interested in getting the last publish/deployment date.

Answer (score 0):

On this page you can find more info on how to get cloud service info based on c# code.

http://gauravmantri.com/2012/03/16/programmatically-finding-deployment-slot-from-code-running-in-windows-azure/

if you can use powershell I would advice this https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn495131.aspx

Comment: thanks for the reply! I will check these out to see if either will achieve the result I need, and will mark your answer as the accepted answer if it does, but regardless, a +1 for the answer!